# Can we declare an interface class by making all the methods abstract using the keyword ‘abstract’ in a class in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to know about the way of defining interface class in C++ by this approach. Is it possible? I don't want to know about interface creation but want to know about the abstract keyword use in C++.

Comment: There is no keyword `abstract` in C++. And if you want an abstract class, that is a class that cannot be initialized, just use a protected constructor.

Comment: There are pure virtual functions though: `= 0`, `abstract` is C#

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: No, an abstract class is one with pure virtual functions that must be overridden, not one with a protected constructor.

Comment: @MikeSeymour MSDN : `They are classes that cannot be instantiated, and are frequently either partially implemented, or not at all implemented.`, Wikipedia: `an abstract type is a type in a nominative type system which cannot be instantiated directly. `. Whether you implement some functionality or just derive from it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: C++11: "A class is abstract if it has at least
one pure virtual function." A class with a protected constructor (and no pure virtual functions) *can* be instantiated directly, by its members, friends, and subclasses, so isn't abstract even by those rather inaccurate descriptions.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Heh, I smiled too much on "can be instantiated by its subclass" to disagree now. You're right.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, an abstract class is any class that has at least 1 *pure* virtual function.

C++ does not have direct support for interfaces, but you can make one by making all of the functions public, virtual, and abstract, and have no data members in the class.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, an interface is defined as follows:

```
class Interface {
public:
    virtual ~Interface();
    virtual void aMethod() = 0;
};
```

Note the virtual destructor.